# DOM HTML Extract infromation with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xpath

hi i'm trying to extract information of this html. but i'm havin trouble when it coms to the desctiption here's is my code

```
 let divCardDes = document.createElement('div');
    divCardDes.className = 'des';
    let pDescription = document.createElement('p');
    let resultDescription = xmlDoc.evaluate('.//div/div[@class="short"]', node, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE);
    pDescription.innerHTML = '<strong>Descripcion: </strong>' + resultDescription.singleNodeValue.p;
    divCardDes.appendChild(pDescription);
    console.log(resultDescription)
```

and the html :

```
<div class="row d-block align-end" data-v-1a4e2f4c="">
<div index="0" class="row" data-v-744a5232="" data-v-1a4e2f4c="">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-3" data-v-744a5232=""><a
            href="/libro-el-peligro-de-estar-cuerda/9788432240645/12789134" title="EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA"
            class="py-2" data-v-744a5232=""><img title="el peligro de estar cuerda-9788432240645"
                alt="el peligro de estar cuerda-9788432240645"
                src="https://imagessl5.casadellibro.com/a/l/t1/45/9788432240645.jpg"
                data-src="https://imagessl5.casadellibro.com/a/l/t1/45/9788432240645.jpg" width="" height=""
                class="show-shadow cdl-img active" style="max-height:undefinedpx;max-width:undefinedpx;"
                data-v-744a5232=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-9" data-v-744a5232="">
        <div class="row row--dense" data-v-744a5232="">
            <div class="col col-11" data-v-744a5232=""><a
                    href="/libro-el-peligro-de-estar-cuerda/9788432240645/12789134"
                    title="EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA" class="title" data-v-744a5232="">
                    EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA
                </a></div>
            <div class="hidden-md-and-down col col-1" data-v-744a5232=""><span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="v-icon notranslate theme--light accent--text" data-v-744a5232=""><svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true"
                        class="v-icon__svg">
                        <path
                            d="M12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24L14.81,8.62L12,2L9.19,8.62L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27Z">
                        </path>
                    </svg></span> <span class="text-subtitle-1" data-v-744a5232="">7</span></div>
            <div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232=""><a href="/libros-ebooks/rosa-montero/9812"
                    class="author text-underline-over" data-v-744a5232="">
                    Rosa Montero
                </a></div>
            <div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232="">
                <div data-v-ce307848="" data-v-744a5232="">
                    <div class="short" style="-webkit-line-clamp:5;" data-v-ce307848="">
                        Una apasionada defensa del valor de ser diferente.Partiendo de su experiencia personal y de
                        la lectura de numerosos libros de psicología, neurociencia, literatura y memorias de grandes
                        autores de distintas disciplinas creativas, Rosa Montero nos ofrece un estudio apasionante
                        sobre los vinculos entre la creatividad y la inestabilidad mental. Y lo hace compartiendo
                        con el lector numerosas curiosidades asombrosas sobre como funciona nuestro cerebro al
                        crear, desmenuzando todos los aspectos que influyen en la creatividad, y montandolos ante
                        los ojos del lector mientras escribe, como un detective dispuesto a resolver las piezas
                        dispersas de una investigacion.Ensayo y ficcion se dan la mano en esta exploracion sobre los
                        vinculos entre la creatividad y la locura, y asi el lector asistira en directo al mismo
                        proceso de la creacion, descubrira la teoria de "la tormenta perfecta", esto es, que en el
                        estallido creativo confluyen una serie de factores irrepetibles, quimicos y situacionales, y
                        compartira la experiencia personal de como Rosa Montero vivio en directo, y durante años,
                        muy cerca de la locura.El peligro de estar cuerda habla de que "las hadas" nos dan un don, y
                        nos hacen pagar un precio por el; los normales no pagamos ese duro precio, pero corremos el
                        riesgo de morir de tedio, en lugar de morir de amor. Como en todo, la clave esta en el
                        equilibrio entre el porcentaje de desapego y el de sentimiento, en lograr cierta armonia
                        entre el yo que sufre y el yo que controla, dice la propia autora.
                    </div>
                    <div class="action" style="" data-v-ce307848=""><a
                            class="success--text text-body-2 accent2--text text-underline-hover" data-v-ce307848=""
                            data-v-744a5232="">
                            Ver más
                        </a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i want to get the text in the last part of the code, the div saying class short. i think the xpath is wrong but i don't know why. could sombody help me?

Comment: What is `resultDescription.singleNodeValue.p` supposed to do or select? Do you want `resultDescription.singleNodeValue.textContent`?

Comment: yes i want the text. i tried changing it as you say but still does not work

Comment: Why use xpath for an HTML document? DOM methods are a lot easier

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a complete but minimal and executable example, the path works for me, assuming you have the `div` in an HTML DOM document:

```js
    let divCardDes = document.createElement('div');
    divCardDes.className = 'des';
    let pDescription = document.createElement('p');
    let resultDescription = document.evaluate('.//div/div[@class="short"]', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE);
    pDescription.innerHTML = '<strong>Descripcion: </strong>' + resultDescription.singleNodeValue.textContent;
    divCardDes.appendChild(pDescription);
    console.log(resultDescription);
    console.log(divCardDes);
    document.body.appendChild(divCardDes);
```

```html
<div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232="">
                <div data-v-ce307848="" data-v-744a5232="">
                    <div class="short" style="-webkit-line-clamp:5;" data-v-ce307848="">
                        Una apasionada defensa del valor de ser diferente.Partiendo de su experiencia personal y de
                        la lectura de numerosos libros de psicología, neurociencia, literatura y memorias de grandes
                        autores de distintas disciplinas creativas, Rosa Montero nos ofrece un estudio apasionante
                        sobre los vinculos entre la creatividad y la inestabilidad mental. Y lo hace compartiendo
                        con el lector numerosas curiosidades asombrosas sobre como funciona nuestro cerebro al.....
                    </div>
               </div>
</div>
```

With your more complex input sample, the path also selects an element and of course you can get the text with `.textContent`:

```js
const html = `<div class="row d-block align-end" data-v-1a4e2f4c="">
<div index="0" class="row" data-v-744a5232="" data-v-1a4e2f4c="">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-3" data-v-744a5232=""><a
            href="/libro-el-peligro-de-estar-cuerda/9788432240645/12789134" title="EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA"
            class="py-2" data-v-744a5232=""><img title="el peligro de estar cuerda-9788432240645"
                alt="el peligro de estar cuerda-9788432240645"
                src="https://imagessl5.casadellibro.com/a/l/t1/45/9788432240645.jpg"
                data-src="https://imagessl5.casadellibro.com/a/l/t1/45/9788432240645.jpg" width="" height=""
                class="show-shadow cdl-img active" style="max-height:undefinedpx;max-width:undefinedpx;"
                data-v-744a5232=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-9" data-v-744a5232="">
        <div class="row row--dense" data-v-744a5232="">
            <div class="col col-11" data-v-744a5232=""><a
                    href="/libro-el-peligro-de-estar-cuerda/9788432240645/12789134"
                    title="EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA" class="title" data-v-744a5232="">
                    EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA
                </a></div>
            <div class="hidden-md-and-down col col-1" data-v-744a5232=""><span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="v-icon notranslate theme--light accent--text" data-v-744a5232=""><svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true"
                        class="v-icon__svg">
                        <path
                            d="M12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24L14.81,8.62L12,2L9.19,8.62L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27Z">
                        </path>
                    </svg></span> <span class="text-subtitle-1" data-v-744a5232="">7</span></div>
            <div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232=""><a href="/libros-ebooks/rosa-montero/9812"
                    class="author text-underline-over" data-v-744a5232="">
                    Rosa Montero
                </a></div>
            <div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232="">
                <div data-v-ce307848="" data-v-744a5232="">
                    <div class="short" style="-webkit-line-clamp:5;" data-v-ce307848="">
                        Una apasionada defensa del valor de ser diferente.Partiendo de su experiencia personal y de
                        la lectura de numerosos libros de psicología, neurociencia, literatura y memorias de grandes
                        autores de distintas disciplinas creativas, Rosa Montero nos ofrece un estudio apasionante
                        sobre los vinculos entre la creatividad y la inestabilidad mental. Y lo hace compartiendo
                        con el lector numerosas curiosidades asombrosas sobre como funciona nuestro cerebro al
                        crear, desmenuzando todos los aspectos que influyen en la creatividad, y montandolos ante
                        los ojos del lector mientras escribe, como un detective dispuesto a resolver las piezas
                        dispersas de una investigacion.Ensayo y ficcion se dan la mano en esta exploracion sobre los
                        vinculos entre la creatividad y la locura, y asi el lector asistira en directo al mismo
                        proceso de la creacion, descubrira la teoria de "la tormenta perfecta", esto es, que en el
                        estallido creativo confluyen una serie de factores irrepetibles, quimicos y situacionales, y
                        compartira la experiencia personal de como Rosa Montero vivio en directo, y durante años,
                        muy cerca de la locura.El peligro de estar cuerda habla de que "las hadas" nos dan un don, y
                        nos hacen pagar un precio por el; los normales no pagamos ese duro precio, pero corremos el
                        riesgo de morir de tedio, en lugar de morir de amor. Como en todo, la clave esta en el
                        equilibrio entre el porcentaje de desapego y el de sentimiento, en lograr cierta armonia
                        entre el yo que sufre y el yo que controla, dice la propia autora.
                    </div>
                    <div class="action" style="" data-v-ce307848=""><a
                            class="success--text text-body-2 accent2--text text-underline-hover" data-v-ce307848=""
                            data-v-744a5232="">
                            Ver más
                        </a></div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
            
const htmlDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');

    let divCardDes = document.createElement('div');
    divCardDes.className = 'des';
    let pDescription = document.createElement('p');
    let resultDescription = htmlDoc.evaluate('.//div/div[@class="short"]', htmlDoc, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE);
    pDescription.innerHTML = '<strong>Descripcion: </strong>' + resultDescription.singleNodeValue.textContent;
    divCardDes.appendChild(pDescription);
    console.log(divCardDes);
    document.body.appendChild(divCardDes);
```

```css
<div class="row d-block align-end" data-v-1a4e2f4c="">
<div index="0" class="row" data-v-744a5232="" data-v-1a4e2f4c="">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-3" data-v-744a5232=""><a
            href="/libro-el-peligro-de-estar-cuerda/9788432240645/12789134" title="EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA"
            class="py-2" data-v-744a5232=""><img title="el peligro de estar cuerda-9788432240645"
                alt="el peligro de estar cuerda-9788432240645"
                src="https://imagessl5.casadellibro.com/a/l/t1/45/9788432240645.jpg"
                data-src="https://imagessl5.casadellibro.com/a/l/t1/45/9788432240645.jpg" width="" height=""
                class="show-shadow cdl-img active" style="max-height:undefinedpx;max-width:undefinedpx;"
                data-v-744a5232=""></a></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10 col-9" data-v-744a5232="">
        <div class="row row--dense" data-v-744a5232="">
            <div class="col col-11" data-v-744a5232=""><a
                    href="/libro-el-peligro-de-estar-cuerda/9788432240645/12789134"
                    title="EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA" class="title" data-v-744a5232="">
                    EL PELIGRO DE ESTAR CUERDA
                </a></div>
            <div class="hidden-md-and-down col col-1" data-v-744a5232=""><span aria-hidden="true"
                    class="v-icon notranslate theme--light accent--text" data-v-744a5232=""><svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" role="img" aria-hidden="true"
                        class="v-icon__svg">
                        <path
                            d="M12,17.27L18.18,21L16.54,13.97L22,9.24L14.81,8.62L12,2L9.19,8.62L2,9.24L7.45,13.97L5.82,21L12,17.27Z">
                        </path>
                    </svg></span> <span class="text-subtitle-1" data-v-744a5232="">7</span></div>
            <div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232=""><a href="/libros-ebooks/rosa-montero/9812"
                    class="author text-underline-over" data-v-744a5232="">
                    Rosa Montero
                </a></div>
            <div class="col col-12" data-v-744a5232="">
                <div data-v-ce307848="" data-v-744a5232="">
                    <div class="short" style="-webkit-line-clamp:5;" data-v-ce307848="">
                        Una apasionada defensa del valor de ser diferente.Partiendo de su experiencia personal y de
                        la lectura de numerosos libros de psicología, neurociencia, literatura y memorias de grandes
                        autores de distintas disciplinas creativas, Rosa Montero nos ofrece un estudio apasionante
                        sobre los vinculos entre la creatividad y la inestabilidad mental. Y lo hace compartiendo
                        con el lector numerosas curiosidades asombrosas sobre como funciona nuestro cerebro al
                        crear, desmenuzando todos los aspectos que influyen en la creatividad, y montandolos ante
                        los ojos del lector mientras escribe, como un detective dispuesto a resolver las piezas
                        dispersas de una investigacion.Ensayo y ficcion se dan la mano en esta exploracion sobre los
                        vinculos entre la creatividad y la locura, y asi el lector asistira en directo al mismo
                        proceso de la creacion, descubrira la teoria de "la tormenta perfecta", esto es, que en el
                        estallido creativo confluyen una serie de factores irrepetibles, quimicos y situacionales, y
                        compartira la experiencia personal de como Rosa Montero vivio en directo, y durante años,
                        muy cerca de la locura.El peligro de estar cuerda habla de que "las hadas" nos dan un don, y
                        nos hacen pagar un precio por el; los normales no pagamos ese duro precio, pero corremos el
                        riesgo de morir de tedio, en lugar de morir de amor. Como en todo, la clave esta en el
                        equilibrio entre el porcentaje de desapego y el de sentimiento, en lograr cierta armonia
                        entre el yo que sufre y el yo que controla, dice la propia autora.
                    </div>
                    <div class="action" style="" data-v-ce307848=""><a
                            class="success--text text-body-2 accent2--text text-underline-hover" data-v-ce307848=""
                            data-v-744a5232="">
                            Ver más
                        </a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: i added the complete html now, thanks fro answering

Comment: @soro, both my samples do select an element and output its `textContent`, the first sample uses the HTML snippet from your original question embedded in the main document, the second parses your larger snippet from your edit with DOMParser as text/html and then applies the XPath from your question.